# jooq query using bind variables

Tags: sql, jdbc, jooq

I using bind variable to do a batch update using below code

```
`var balanceUpdate = dslContext.batch(
                dslContext.update(BALANCE)
                .set(BALANCE.BALANCE, (BigDecimal) null)            
                .where(BALANCE.ID.eq((String) null)));
        balances.forEach(balance -> {
            balanceUpdate.bind(
                    balance.getAmount()
                    balance.Id);
        });
        int[] execute = balanceUpdate.execute();
```

`

Above code work well, but now i want to use bind with array of arguments like

```
var balanceUpdate = dslContext.batch(
                    dslContext.update(BALANCE)
                            .set(BALANCE.BALANCE, (BigDecimal) null)
                            .where(BALANCE.ID.eq((String) null)));
           
            var arguments = balances.stream()
                    .map(balance -> 
                                new Object[] {
                                 balance.getAmount(), 
                                 balance.Id
            }).collect(Collectors.toList());
            
            int[] execute = balanceUpdate.bind(arguments).execute();
```

I get exception

```
java.lang.ArrayStoreException: arraycopy: element type mismatch: can not cast one of the elements of java.lang.Object[] to the type of the destination array, java.math.BigDecimal
    at org.jooq_3.14.4.ORACLE12C.debug(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3722)
    at org.jooq.tools.Convert.convertArray(Convert.java:357)
    at org.jooq.tools.Convert.convertArray(Convert.java:345)
    at org.jooq.tools.Convert$ConvertAll.from(Convert.java:603)
    at org.jooq.tools.Convert.convert0(Convert.java:392)
    at org.jooq.tools.Convert.convert(Convert.java:384)
    at org.jooq.tools.Convert.convert(Convert.java:458)
    at org.jooq.tools.Convert.convertArray(Convert.java:363)
    at org.jooq.tools.Convert.convertArray(Convert.java:345)
    at org.jooq.tools.Convert$ConvertAll.from(Convert.java:614)
    at org.jooq.tools.Convert.convert0(Convert.java:392)
    at org.jooq.tools.Convert.convert(Convert.java:384)
    at org.jooq.tools.Convert.convert(Convert.java:458)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractDataType.convert(AbstractDataType.java:534)
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultDataType.convert(DefaultDataType.java:86)
    at org.jooq.impl.DSL.val(DSL.java:24409)
    at org.jooq.impl.DSL.val(DSL.java:24377)
    at org.jooq.impl.Tools.field(Tools.java:1794)
    at org.jooq.impl.Tools.fields(Tools.java:1865)
    at org.jooq.impl.BatchSingle.executePrepared(BatchSingle.java:226)
    at org.jooq.impl.BatchSingle.execute(BatchSingle.java:170)
```

According [docs](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/BatchBindStep.html#bind(java.lang.Object%5B%5D...)) it should work ? Atleast it works without explicit casting when using jdbc. Is there anyway to get it work to sent bind variables only once instead of many times like in first example?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're calling the wrong [`BatchBindStep.bind(Object...)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/BatchBindStep.html#bind(java.lang.Object...)) method, or at least not in the way you're expecting. There's currently no overload accepting a collection of type `List<Object[]>`. So, what you should do instead is create an `Object[][]` type for your bind variable sets:

```java
Object[][] arguments = balances
    .stream()
    .map(balance -> new Object[] {
        balance.getAmount(), 
        balance.Id
    }).toArray();
```